# How can i stack multiple array in localStorage javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm having a problem in my app where i will store the data in the localStorage everytime the client enter a case. here's my html using modal.

```
           <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control date-picker" placeholder="Month and Year" id="c_round" name="c_round">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="prov" name="prov">
                        <option>Select Province</option>
                        <option value="01">Province1</option>
                        <option value="02">Province2</option>
                        <option value="03">Province3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="mun" name="mun">
                        <option>Select Municipality</option>
                        <option value="01">Municipality1</option>
                        <option value="02">Municipality2</option>
                        <option value="03">Municipality3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="brgy" name="brgy">
                        <option>Select Barangay</option>
                        <option value="001">Barangay1</option>
                        <option value=:002>Barangay2</option>
                        <option value="003">Barangay3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="commodity" class="control-label text-left">Household Classification</label>
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <input type="radio" name="h_classification" value="Farming"> Farming &emsp;&emsp;
                        <input type="radio" name="h_classification" value="Non-Farming"> Non-Farming
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--End modal body-->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" id="create" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" >Create</button>
            </div>
```

When the client click the Create button the data will store in the localStorage here's my jquery.

```
$(function() {

var round = $("#c_round");
var prov  = $("#prov");
var mun   = $("#mun");
var brgy  = $("#brgy");
var h_classification = $("[name='h_classification']");
var btn_create = $('#create');
var dataObject = [];

btn_create.on('click', function(){ 
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined"){
        dataObj = [{
            'user_id': user_id,
            'prov'   : prov.val(),
            'mun'    : mun.val(),
            'brgy'   : brgy.val(),
            'r_code' : r_code,
            'h_class': h_classification.val()
        }];

        dataObject.push(dataObj);

        localStorage.setItem('dataObject', JSON.stringify(dataObject));

        retrivedOjects = localStorage.getItem('dataObject');

        console.log('retrivedOjects: ', JSON.parse(retrivedOjects));
    }else {
        alert("Error: Localstorage not supported");
    }
});

});
```

When i refresh the page the old data is still there but when i create new data the old data is replaced by new data it doesn't append.

I want to stack many arrays in the localStorage("dataObjects") first before sending it on to the server for my offline mode application,

(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `dataObject` to whatever is currently in localStorage before pushing new data to it.

```
var dataObject = [];
btn_create.on('click', function() { 
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.getItem('dataObject') && localStorage.getItem('dataObject').length > 0)
            dataObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dataObject'));
        dataObj = {
            'user_id': user_id,
            'prov'   : prov.val(),
            'mun'    : mun.val(),
            'brgy'   : brgy.val(),
            'r_code' : r_code,
            'h_class': h_classification.val()
        };
        dataObject.push(dataObj);
        localStorage.setItem('dataObject', JSON.stringify(dataObject));

        retrivedOjects = localStorage.getItem('dataObject');

        console.log('retrivedOjects: ', JSON.parse(retrivedOjects));
    } else {
        alert("Error: Localstorage not supported");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! @Villa7_

Comment: why when the dataObject is empty or localStorage is empty it returns error of dataObject is null cannot push

Comment: oh i figure it out anyway thnks hehe

Answer (score 1):

you need to get the old data from local storage and then push the new object to the old data. Then you can save it back to local storage.

```
var oldObject = localStorage.getItem('dataObject');
oldObject.push(dataObject);
localStorage.setItem('dataObject', JSON.stringify(dataObject));
```